# POST Headers being sent, but not received on server

Tags: php, http, post

In C#, I am working on a project to automatically update a separate server with an image and other form data and such... However, the PHP server isn't getting any of the POST data, it's only getting the headers and I can't figure out why.

Here is what I am sending to the server (all new lines have CRLF):

```
POST /new_reply/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.104
User-Agent: Update Bot
Cookie: SID=sib5m5lgaq66vfp2nfhpab6ug0;UID=bot
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----xxx
Content-Length: 1903

-----xxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_sent"

1
-----xxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"


-----xxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body"

hej fra mig
-----xxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(image data)
-----xxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post"

Post
-----xxx--
```

Here is the image with the hidden characters show of the request:
[image]

Here is the PHP print_r of $_REQUEST on the page /new_reply/1:

```
Array
(
    [reply] => 1
    [SID] => sib5m5lgaq66vfp2nfhpab6ug0
    [UID] => bot
)
```

As you can see, none of the post is coming through...

Comment: What's in `$_FILES`?  Is the file upload at least coming through?

Comment: Maybe check `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` to see if the data is being received, and it's just a problem with PHP parsing it. It could be empty for various reasons though, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data.

Comment: Hm. I don't think it's that, since $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is null.

Comment: What about `php://input`, as described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the boundary specified in the `Content-Type` header is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=RANDOM_STRING_BOUNDARY
--RANDOM_STRING_BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_name"

Monkey
--RANDOM_STRING_BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="monkey.png"
Content-Type: image/png

[ here would be the png file in binary form ]
--RANDOM_STRING_BOUNDARY--
```

As you can see, RANDOM_STRING_BOUNDARY has no hyphens prepended when specified in the `Content-Type` header, only in the subsequent headers where it is actually used. Also, the last usage appends two  new hyphens (but you already knew that).

Comment: He, I've been bitten by something similar. For me, it was the trailing hyphens that were missing :)

Comment: I was having a similar issue, although it seems like everything has a different way of formatting the POST request body that somehow works until a human being tries to generate it on their own. The fact that you didn't need the dashes in the boundary field, and then you did afterwards seemed to be what tripped me up.